# Groovy class files not included in deployment

Tags: groovy, myeclipse

I have two java projects, A and B, A depends on B. In project B I've added a groovy class (Foo.groovy) and a java class (Bar.java) that uses the groovy class. In MyEclipse, Foo.class is in bin-groovy, and I can run things from MyEclipse just fine. However, when MyEclipse deploys project A to tomcat, it does not include the Foo.class file so Bar.java can't run. If I manually copy Foo.class to tomcat, it works just fine. Is this just a MyEclipse issue? It's driving me crazy because all that needs to happen is to have the .class files from the groovy classes get included on a deploy, it seems like that should be an easy configuration, but I have not found a solution for this yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Where are the missing files in the source structure?  Are they in grails-app or src/groovy?
2. When you deploy via CL what happens (i.e. grails war or similar command)

Comment: The missing file is in a package with java files. The project is a java project that I just installed the groovy plugin and added groovy nature to the project. I added the groovy class to handle some better string manipulation. Perhaps the source structure is a problem?

I haven't modified the ant script for the build, so I have not deployed via CL yet. I did manually copy the .class file to the deployment and it worked.